# Check first day of week in a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I would like to check if a current input date, is the same week as my timestamps in the database. I do this by looking at the week number of a date.

I am trying to use the:

```
Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime, ...)
```

method, which normally works.

**However, when I use LINQ, I get**:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities [...]
```

**My code:**

```
 var ordersWeek = orders.Where(c => 
                (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Timestamp).Value.Year == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now).Value.Year) &&
                (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Timestamp).Value.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now).Value.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday))
                ).ToList();
```

In this particular code i try to use this extension method:

```
  public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }

        return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff);
    }
```

What is the best way to do this in LINQ? Remember you cannot use the `.Date` function.

Comment: LINQ to Entities is a quite limited comparing with LINQ to objects. Please, post entire LINQ expression.

Comment: If you are using Linq to Entities, this would be why it fails.  There is no supported way to translate that method into sql.  Try using the method outside the sql, then join on it.

Comment: How would you write it in SQL, without LINQ?  Figure that out first, then figure out how to map that to LINQ.

Comment: I guess you have to calculate Week Start Date and End Date based on your input date at C# end, then use that date range to compare in your LINQ query like `c.TimeStamp >= StartDate && c.TimeStamp <= EndDate`.

Comment: @Habib yep, that solved my problem. Thanks! if you make an answer I will accept it, and then we've helped hundreds of Googlers over the next years :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your extension method `StartOfWeek` is just visible to your C# code, There is no way for entity framework to translate into underlying data source language *(possibly SQL)*. Similarly if you try to use [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx), it would fail with the same reason as EF won't be able to translate it.

Instead you can do:

- Calculate Start Date and End Date for your Week
- Use that range to query in your LINQ query like `c.TimeStamp >= StartDate && c.TimeStamp <= EndDate`

Code:

```
DateTime startDate = dt.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(6);
```

With your Extension method:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static DateTime StartOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
    {
        int diff = dt.DayOfWeek - startOfWeek;
        if (diff < 0)
        {
            diff += 7;
        }

        return dt.AddDays(-1*diff);
    }
}
```

and then in your LINQ query:

```
var ordersWeek = orders.Where(c =>
                (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Timestamp).Value.Year == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now).Value.Year) &&
                (EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Timestamp).Value >= startDate && 
                EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(c.Timestamp).Value <= endDate)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: There appears to be a problem with this... the signature of the extension method should have "this DateTime dt".  Or at least, that's what I had to do to get it to work in my solution.  Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @SailingJudo, you are absolutely right, somehow I missed it, please feel free to edit yourself in future, thanks for pointing it out.